Mysterious Figure
In the heart of darkness
Where shadows play
A figure stands
With a face of gray
It's eyes are black
It's soul is white
It weeps for the living
And mourns the night
It's presence is felt
By the wind & rain
Yet it's invisible
Like a ghostly stain
What is the figure?

"it's eyes" means "it is eyes" not "the eyes of it." Leave off the apostrophes in those three lines unless the error is deliberately part of the puzzle

Did you make this riddle?
